# How to play audios in order with only one click in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build a web app running in mobile device (iOS, Android). Suppose I have 4 audio files(English for 2, Chinese for 2), and I have a dropdown to select one of them, after select one language, it will load into my small project.

After loading a certain language, and if the user clicks a start button, it will play the first audio and then wait some certain seconds(Maybe 5), then play the second audio automatically. If i have 10 audio files in the future, then it will play all of them in order with only **one click**

How should I achieve this? My idea is maybe I can use time series to control audio flow but not sure how.

I have looked some function like onEnded function, but it needs the user interaction after the first audio is done playing.

Also, there are some NPM package such as react-audio-player and react-sound but they don't seem to support what I want.

Comment: You need to show some code so we can get a better understanding of how you are going about essentially creating this playlist.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I just have an idea so far but I haven't programmed it. Is it ok if I can reach you via email or some other media once I have done some programming?